# React Native does not rerender component after splice or push in to an Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have code like bellow

```
const array = [  {
    _id: 5e45652ad75f432c79622f17,
    owner: '5e44ed54acebcc2102da5244',
    videoID: '',
    totalTime: 60,
    totalView: 100,
  },
  {
    _id: 5e45652dd75f432c79622f18,
    owner: '5e44ed54acebcc2102da5244',
    videoID: '',
    totalTime: 60,
    totalView: 100,
  },
  {
    _id: 5e45652ed75f432c79622f19,
    owner: '5e44ed54acebcc2102da5244',
    videoID: '',
    totalTime: 60,
    totalView: 100,
  }
]
const [CurrentListVideo, onChangeCurrentListVideo] = React.useState(array);
function spliceOneItem(){
  console.log('before splice',CurrentListVideo)//3 item
  CurrentListVideo.splice(0,1)
  console.log('after splice',CurrentListVideo)//2 item
  onChangeCurrentListVideo(CurrentListVideo)//then i call this
}
```

and some code in return() like bellow

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={spliceOneItem} style={styles.button}>
</TouchableOpacity>
{
  CurrentListVideo.map(thisVideo=>{
   return <ListRunning key={thisVideo._id} waitForDelete={deleteVideo} thisVideo={thisVideo}/>
  })
}
```

when i press that TouchableOpacity, every thing work correctly but at

```
CurrentListVideo.map(thisVideo=>{
   return <ListRunning key={thisVideo._id} waitForDelete={deleteVideo} thisVideo={thisVideo}/>
  })
```

still have 3 item, it took me 2 day for this problem, please help

Answer (score 0):

well, it easy than i think, just add [...]

```
onChangeCurrentListVideo([...CurrentListVideo])
```